# Django gets really slow when DEBUG = False

Tags: django

I've got a Django application that's running fine in debug mode. By "running fine" I mean no errors and "near instant" page loads. When I turn debug mode off by setting DEBUG = False, page loads become *very* slow, typically 60-80 seconds per page.

No other changes were made, and no errors appear in the logs.

I'm using the development web server and SQLite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end I believe the problem I was having was related to the way static media files are served by the Django dev server and following setting which is in my urls.py:

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        (r'^media/(?P.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
         {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
    )

I fixed this by getting apache and mod_wsgi set up on the staging server and not using the dev server when debug mode is off.

Answer (score 2):

Well, be sure that you are not using IPv6. Because I got this same problem with you.

Just don't use localhost:8000, instead, using 127.0.0.1:8000.

Be sure you make changes to the listening address and port in django .

Comment: That's not it. I've been using 127.0.0.1 in the browser, and INTERNAL_IPS is set to that as well.

Comment: Django also logs all sql queries when in debug mode, which can also slow your site down if you have lots of queries, thought i dont think this will take up to minutes...

Comment: @lazerscience The op is saying that `DEBUG=FALSE` so that is not it.